# Unattended Installation Miktex

Tags: installing

we are trying to figure out if there is possibility make an unattended installation of miktex. We would like to force the installation path in the user spaces, so the user can update the packages without admin right.

Comment: https://miktex.org/howto/deploy-miktex

Comment: Tanks Man! just to understand if i run "miktexsetup --verbose --local-package-repository=C:\temp\miktex --package-set=complete download" i will install all the packages available right?

Comment: @giovannibaldi just for the record Ulrike is a female consultant on MiKTeX  and the command given is only to download to the server the current full collection (several GB) which may need to be updated every few days for any updated packages. The user installs should NOT be administrative (just BASIC single user) and they need to point to the full server copy as their source for instant updates thus they could fall behind ordinary single users if the server is not updated regularly

Comment: Tanks for the Reply. The problems we have is because we are trying to distribute Miktek on request  via SCCM. So the installer run with a special user provided by SCCM with administrative right but it fail because of this special users. So we would like to install using the user profile path, where the user has full privilege and he can update packages without calling every time the sys admin to put his password